# GWT Startup Sequence optimization

Tags: gwt, optimization, startup

Reading the Goole 2010 IO pdf of : "Architecting for Performance with Google Web Toolkit", I found this  approach to reduce startup time :

Better: 2 round trips:
First:
 - Host Page
 - Script URL
 - Initial Data
Second:
 - Compiled Script

It is not the Default GWT setup:
4 round trips
 - Host page
 - Selection Script
 - Compiled Script
 - Initial Data

My problem is that I do not how to do to acheive the "2 round trip solution". Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually rather easy:

- inline the selection script in your page (can be done with a special GWT Linker, or using a JSP include directive for instance –I've successfully been using the latter, much easier– and add a `<meta name='moduleName::gwt:property' content='baseUrl=moduleName/'>` to tell the inlined selection script where to find the compiled permutation.
  Technically, you could go even farther and replace the selection script with server-side content negotiation. I believe Google does that (e.g. for Google Groups) but it's a bit harder (made way simpler with modularization of the `CrossSiteIframeLinker`, but still not that easy).
- for the initial data, see https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page and http://jectbd.com/?p=1174 (I've been using AutoBeans to pass user information and application settings to the GWT app)